# Views base64 encoded blob in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, base64, blob

having a bit of trouble Im trying to view a base64 encoded image which is held on my server as a blob. I want to view this inside either with an image tag or echo it as an html file which I can reference to with an image tag.

The problem is the blob data returns wrong from my server.

```
    <?php

       $select = "SELECT `data` 
               FROM  `sandbox`.`photos` 
               WHERE `id` = 4
               LIMIT 0 , 1";

        $result = mysql_query($select, $connection);



         while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){

           $blob_data = $row[0];

           echo "$blob_data";

           }

    ?>
```

The problem is that this retuns 5.533782782 * E.

How do I view this as an image? Do I need to deencode it?

Comment: Stylistic remark: Use `echo $blob_data`. There's no need to quote variables.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($blob_data).'">';
```

Comment: Or you could do that - but I don't think that is 100% cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

You may use mysql [cast or convert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function. You can also try [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are not creative - they store the data you put in pretty much exactly as you put it in, and then retrieve that exact data.

This means that if you encode data into base64 before you insert it, you will have to decode from base64 to get meaningful information out.

---

Note: you are probably better off storing the file as an image in the filesystem, and a filepath in your database rather than just putting the image directly into your database

You can use any filepath you want, even from outside of the document root (though care should be taken not to allow traversal/display of sensitive files):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){

  $file_path = $row[0];

  echo file_get_contents($file_path);

}
```

Comment: thanks however I want to dynamically reference the images so to the database they go.

Comment: What aspect of a 'dynamically referenced' image precludes storing it in the filesystem?