# How to display images stored in database as a blob, in webpage

Tags: javascript, sql, image, html

I want to display a image in webpage , which is stored in database as blob type. I am storing a image as binary/image type in database successfully. But how can i display it in webpage. I am getting a image as something like symbols(�����JFIF��`�`�����fExif��II*���������>) when i retrieve from the database.

Comment: you need to write something to serve the image at a URL and then use an `img` tag

Comment: Why are you storing the actual image in the database? Upload the file, store the file name echo out the path in an img tag...

Comment: @RickCalder - Depending on the size of the images, there are pros and cons to each approach. It's not as straightforward as everyone seems to think. (And as I used to think.) This is just one of many articles highlighting the pros and cons. http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/07/10/image-storage-database-or-file-system/

Comment: I suppose it's true in some cases, although his testing criteria was seriously flawed. I don't personally think it's a good solution for regular use and particularly for large images or large numbers of users. I just don't see it as a scalable solution to be honest. The only real upside I can personally see is the ease with which you can make no longer used images go away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should convert image data to base64 and then write to response, for example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD
 NCAMAAAAsYgRbAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c
 cllPAAAABJQTFRF3NSmzMewPxIG//ncJEJsldTou1jHgAAAARBJREFUeNrs2EEK
 gCAQBVDLuv+V20dENbMY831wKz4Y/VHb/5RGQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ
 0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0PzMWtyaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoxtb0QGho
 aGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaMbRLEvv50VTQ9OTQ5OpyZ01GpM2g0bfmDQaL7S+ofFC6x
 v3ZpxJiywakzbvd9r3RWPS9I2+MWk0+kbf0Hih9Y17U0nTHibrDDQ0NDQ0NDQ0
 NDQ0NDQ0NTXbRSL/AK72o6GhoaGhoRlL8951vwsNDQ0NDQ1NDc0WyHtDTEhD
 Q0NDQ0NTS5MdGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGposzSHAAErMwwQ2HwRQ
 AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="beastie.png" />
```

http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/

Or you can make a link to server script which return header with content type of any image and write image data directly to response.

Comment: i already test that, work fine in ie7-9, firefox, opera, chrome, may be old browsers not support like ie6, i haven't any ability to test on ie6

Comment: If you have php server side language you should use base64_encode for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498843/views-base64-encoded-blob-in-html-with-php, if you have asp.net server side you should use Convert.ToBase64String Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I used when I had to render a binary image from the database (SQL Server) into a html page using Ajax

```
stm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT IMAGE FROM TABLE" );
rs = stm.executeQuery();
return rs
```

The raw rs is then received using ajax(stored in the "response"):

```
        $.post('./getImagePage.jsp', {
            action : 'getImage'
        }, function(response) {         
            if (response != ''){                                                        
                var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( response[0].IMAGE);                                       
                var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpg" } );
                var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );                                  
                var img = document.querySelector("#fotoMb");
                img.src = imageUrl;                     
        });
```

And the HTML:

```
<img id="fotoMb" style="border:5px solid;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to don't save image to database !
That's can make your database server loading slowly !
Short answer, save image on folder of you web server and only refer the url where you save your file.
Good luck !